# Calculate $\int_{|z|=3} \frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $\int_{|z|=3} \frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}dz$

Firstly we see that all the singular points lie in the circle $|z|<3$. However I don't have idea how to calculate it.

Comment: The function is meromorphic inside that disk, so I think you can just use the residue theorem.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use something quicker than the commented suggestion, although I see @Conrad already submitted something close in spirit to what I thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the singularities are inside $|z|=3$, one can move the integration circle to $|z|=R>3$ and let $R \to \infty$ which gives a nice result by the "coincidence" that the numerator has degree one less than the denominator, so only the ratio of leading terms matters.

Concretely, using $dz=izd\theta$ one gets that:

$I=\int_{|z|=3} \frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}dz=\int_{|z|=R} \frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{iz^{18}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}d\theta, z=Re^{i\theta}$, so

$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i}{(1+2/z^2)^3(1+3/z^3)^4}d\theta, z=Re^{i\theta}$ hence $I=I_R \to 2\pi i$ as $|z|=R \to \infty$

so the integral is $2\pi i$

Answer (score 0):

A variant on @Conrad's approach:

With $z=3e^{i\theta}$ the integral becomes $i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(3z)^{18}e^{i\theta}d\theta}{(9e^{2i\theta}+2)^3)(27e^{3i\theta}+3)^4}$. Discounting the factor of $i$ I've moved outside, the numerator and denominator are both degree-$18$ polynomials in $e^{i\theta}$, with leading coefficient $3^{18}$. The integrand is therefore a rational function that has constant term $1$, making the final result $i\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=2\pi i$, since other powers of $e^{i\theta}$ integrate to $0$.